# DotNetNuke: load data in session at login time

Tags: session, authentication, dotnetnuke

I'm using DNN 5. When a user logs in, I want to load some data into the session. Where should I add my code? Should I intervene into the `login.aspx`'s code behind?

Comment: If you add to the login that comes with DNN you risk your code breaking when you upgrade - look at copying the login and adding it there - wonder why tyou want to use session though

Comment: Thanks. I need to add some data to the session when the user is loaded. Thus I can avoid a RTT to the DB when I load some modules.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions seems to be [writing a custom authentication provider](http://blog.theaccidentalgeek.com/post/2009/07/13/DotNetNuke-Tips-and-Tricks-12-Creating-your-own-Authentication-Provider.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set the page the users sees upon login and add a custom module to that page. That would get you out of writing an authentication provider.